# Modifying glBlendColor from within a vertex/fragment shader

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, blending, freetype, color-blending

I'm using a blending function to colorize glyphs obtained from the freetype library when using subpixel rendering (LCD, glyph bitmap format is RGB (not alpha)):

I upload the texture in RGB format to the GPU and used the following blending:

```
glBlendFunc( GL_CONSTANT_COLOR_EXT,  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR );
glBlendColor( r, g, b, 1 );
```

r,g,b is the desired glyph color. This works great as long as glyphs are all the same color (I'm using a single vertex buffer). I would like now to have different color for each glyph and then, I would need to specify a different blend color from within the shader but I think it is not possible. Does anyone know how this could be done (if feasible at all) ?

The related project is [available here](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/)

I thought at some point I've found the "right" shader but it is wrong in fact (see [issue 48](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/issues/detail?id=48))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. And there's really no reason to. Just use a per-vertex color, then multiply the values you get from your texture by this per-vertex color.

However, if you *really* want to do it this way, you can [write a second color from the fragment shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Dual-source_blending), if you have GL 3.3:

```
layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 textureColor;
layout(location = 0, index = 1) out vec4 glyphColor;
```

You can then [use that in your blending equation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Dual_Source_Blending):

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC1_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

But really, this is pointless in your case. Just use the fragment shader to multiply them together.

Comment: Just multiplying the texture color with a per-vertex color will result in loss of information, no (with subpixel rendering, anti-aliasing is done using full RGB pixels) ?

If, for example, I want to draw glyph in black, multiplying the glyph texture by black color results in black for RGB and only alpha will anti-alias the glyph but using only gray levels. With the blend func / blend color, I can keep this information.

Comment: @NicolasRougier: Then you need to make a decision: do you want to force dual-source blending (and therefore force the user to have GL 3.3+ class hardware)? Or do you want to take the *very minor* visual quality loss from doing the multiplication first and blending with the alpha, the way most OpenGL applications render text? Sub-pixel antialiasing isn't worth the effort in this case. Especially when it stops you from using [techniques like this](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but subpixel rendering/positioning is quite critical to have flawless rendering at small to medium font size. This might be not so important for a game, but for web browser this is a critical issue.

Comment: @NicolasRougier: "Quite critical" is in the eye of the beholder, as I turned that stuff off. We seem to have rendered small and medium sized fonts reasonably well before sub-pixel rendering. But more importantly, I have outlined your options. You can either have slightly less accurate subpixel rendering, you can restrict yourself to GL 3.3-class hardware, or you're forced to draw each quad in a different draw call. These are the only options that OpenGL gives you, if you want to perform the math you are trying to perform. Remember: subpixel rendering is *normally* done on the CPU.

Comment: Here is a reference on why hinting/kerning/subpixel is "critical":
http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/


I've come up with this code which is not so bad (but not perfect):

`vec4 c = texture2D(texture, uv);
 float t = max(max(c.r,c.g),c.b);
 vec4 color = vec4(gl_Color.rgb, (c.r+c.g+c.b)/3.0);
 color = t*color + (1.0-t)*vec4(c.r,c.g,c.b, min(min(c.r,c.g),c.b));
 gl_FragColor = vec4( color.rgb, gl_Color.a*color.a);
`

Again thanks for the GL 3.3 help, I did not know about it. Since I want the library to be usable with GL 2.0, I'll stick with the solution above.

Comment: @NicolasRougier: "hinting/kerning/subpixel" Each of these are 3 different things. Indeed, kerning is unrelated to the rasterization of a glyph; it's about the placement of a glyph relative to other glyphs.

Comment: I know but for accurate kerning, you need to be able to position a glyph with sub-pixel accuracy. My initial question regarding blending function is related to this sub-pixel positioning (see freetype-gl).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: "Sub-pixel antialiasing isn't worth the effort in this case. Especially when it stops you from using techniques like this [Signed Distance Field]" : if you checked the OP's link you would know, that this library does also have support for SDF. Moreover, SDF for font redering produces blurry text at small font sizes on low pixel density displays; see http://blog.qt.digia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/distance-field-widgets.png note, that these are still quite large font sizes!